# Problems customizing edit and delete links in Symfony's admin generator, any tips?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I'm having some problems customizing edit and delete links in Symfony's admin generator. I don't want to have my edit and delete links as `<LI>`, but all methods available (`linkToDelete` and `getLinkToAction`) return the `<LI>` no matter what.

How can i get around this? Symfony is pretty effed up due to this orphan HTML issue. Terrible framework to work with when customizing beyond what has been already done.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many modules you have in your backend, you could either override the partial that renders these links in each of the modules (yes, you will have duplicate code then) or create a new theme (based on your default) and fix it there.

(And yes, the out of the box Symfony Admin Generator works fine if it's 'good enough'. If you need anything more then you're screwed :-) )

Comment: Can i have something similar to Admin Generator but using normal modules instead? Have a "generic theme" for all my modules so i don't have to customize them every time.

Comment: You could create a custom abstract base sfActions class which implements the list/edit/create actions. You could create some abstract functions in this class like `getModelName()`, to get the specifics.